# how to override/extend chisel signal naming

Tags: chisel

It seems not an easy thing to do or even impossible, but we are using a naming convention that prefix or postfix signals with "i_" or "o_" for inputs/outputs in verilog.

Is there some method to mess with or override inside the chisel library to to that?

I saw that except for clock and reset, all signals have "io" prefix.
Is is possible to use just "i" for input and "o" for output?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this is to probably use a [`MultiIOModule`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.2.1/chisel3/MultiIOModule.html). However, you can also do it with [`suggestName`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.2.1/chisel3/Data.html#suggestName(name:=%3EString):HasId.this.type). Both approaches are shown below.

### MultiIOModule

This a more flexible `Module` that lets you call the `IO` method to add ports to a module more than once. (`Module` requires that you define an `io` member and only allows you to call `IO` once.)

Because `MultiIOModule` frees you from the constraints of `val io = ...` you can use the prefix/postfix naming that you want with the names of your vals. Reflective naming will then get these right in the generated Verilog.

Consider the following Chisel code:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.stage.{ChiselStage, ChiselGeneratorAnnotation}

class Foo extends MultiIOModule {

  val i_bar = IO(Input(Bool()))
  val o_baz = IO(Output(Bool()))

  o_baz := ~i_bar

}

(new ChiselStage).execute(Array.empty, Seq(ChiselGeneratorAnnotation(() => new Foo)))
```

This produces the following Verilog:

```
module Foo(
  input   clock,
  input   reset,
  input   i_bar,
  output  o_baz
);
  assign o_baz = ~ i_bar;
endmodule
```

### SuggestName

As an alternative, you can use the `suggestName` method to change the name to be different from what reflective naming (getting the name from the name of the `val`) would use.

Using `suggestName` you can coerce the names to be whatever you want. The following Chisel produces the same Verilog as above:

```scala
class Foo extends MultiIOModule {

  val a = IO(Input(Bool())).suggestName("i_bar")
  val b = IO(Output(Bool())).suggestName("o_baz")

  b := ~a

}
```

Comment: This solves part of the problem. The val name is actually a base for further chained naming of Bundle hierachies. It is not a property decided prefix, yet make possible to rename the IO by it's nature. But I guess IO property based naming will break "<>" op.